# How to improve search?

Tags: search, web, search-results

[Jakob Nielsen](http://www.useit.com/jakob/) have since 1996 published the article "[Top 10 Mistakes in Web Design](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/9605.html)", recently updated 2011.  At the top of the list we find the mistake **Bad Search**. It has not always been that way. In 2005 it was listed as number 5, and in 2003 it was not listed at all.

From experience I know it is often much better to search using an external search engine with keywords and the extension `site:theWebSite.com`.  This technique works on Google, Bing and Yahoo and most likely some more search engines. Problem is that it's probably not known and used as much as it could be. It leaves those users with either navigating the structure on the site or using the web sites internal search engine. If it is bad, the user will probably not find what she wants and move away from the site.

Now, Jakob Nielsen is not the only one expressing the problem with search. [Peter Morville](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/au/561), author of Information Architecture for the World Wide Web, says that search is the "[worst usability problem on the Web](http://radar.oreilly.com/2010/02/search-is-the-webs-fun-and-wic.html)". Still "search" is one of the most used technique to find content on the web. I often see misspelled words that does not render a search result, nor a suggested word list (see example image below). *BBC do suggest when I type though*.

[image: BBC search result on misspelled word]

At the back end professionals struggle to improve search in different ways. Real-time display of possible keywords based on the characters entered in the search textbox is one. Improving ontology and taxonomy is another. Display suggested words when there is no search result, could be yet another way to improve search. But are there more to do to improve search?

Comment: +1 for the great question, yes their is a need to break the shackles in search modules!!.. hope to get good answers

Comment: I suggest a tag for Web, if this is about search results that are web pages. The issues differ between searching within a site, an OS or even a program.

Comment: Search has improved by leaps and bounds in the last 8 years. Remember "search for keyword" vs "search for phrase"? Ugh. Perhaps how search has already changed would be a good question...

Comment: There're literally books written on this subject. This question can't be answered. See [Lou Rosenfeld's Search Analytics for Your Site](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1933820209/) and [Greg Nudelman's Designing Search](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0470942231/).

Comment: Seems like both Jakob Nielsen and Peter Morville disagrees with you, Ben. I'm not after a book as a reply on this question, just a direction of what to do more than those suggestion mentioned in the question @dnbrv. There are quite a few answers (mine included) on UX.SE which refers to books. That doesn't mean the answers or questions are invalid or that it took a book to answer the question. Question is not "how do you analyze, design, configure, implement and maintain search?". The question is "how to improve search?" which I believe can be answered in ten sentences.

Comment: @BennySkogberg: Search is complicated. It can't be improved in 1000 characters.

Comment: Agreed, "search" is a very complicated thing. It's how many people experience the web, it's on millions of pages. It has many problems and many solutions, I think this needs more focus. The question as outlied hardly even indicates what specific problems there are with search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone had an answer that wasn't 'in a book' or 'copy Google' they'd probably keep their lips sealed for exactly the reason your questions alludes to: search is big business and still often a big problem, if you can make it better you can make money.

In the interim here's a few things that most websites are missing from their search functionality that Google currently offers:

- Type aheads. They reduce spelling errors and help to offer search queries that you already have answers for.
- 'Did you mean' text that offers alternative search queries. Often fixing spelling problems and, again, leading to queries you can recognise.
- Multi media, multi-resource results i.e. images, videos, articles rather than just links to the articles on your site.

Working at a search-based company I know that it's painfully slow to update your search capabilities and introduce new features. It's not cost effective for smaller businesses or those that aren't primarily search platforms e.g. BBC. Having said that, lots of companies just use embedded google or bing searches whereby Google actually handles the search for them but only delivers results that relate to their domain name.

I'd say at present the best, low-cost way for people to improve their onsite search would be to use google's custom search https://cse.google.co.uk/cse/ and at very least offer results from their whole spectrum of content i.e. most business currently have their site plus social media accounts that have accessibly apis etc.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that we can certainly improve search and a lot can be done to make both the technology and experience efficient and user friendly.

### With current technologies

Given the current state of technology, I think the following should be included in search engines:

- **Auto-suggest**
- **Better categorisation**. Now, this can go bad if not implemented
  properly as [discussed on this article at NN/g](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/search-visible-and-simple/). This is part of scoped search and it can lead    to bad UX
  if the search engine forces categories by default. *It's useful when you use it limit the scope in case of too many results rather than forcing it on the user.*

We can
take a hint from previous version of spotlight.

[image]

The search    query
was categorised based on metadata. We replicated this behavior    on
our search engine and observed better findability from users.
[image]

### Future

I believe future search engines should be based on **Natural Language Processing (NLP)** and **Machine Learning (ML)**. Instead of looking for an item and then filtering it according to your needs, the search engine should do it in the background with the help of NLP and ML. Let's say, we're looking for a cheap thumb drive made by Transcend. In current search engines, we have to type thumb drive in search and then filter results based on our needs. Instead, we should be able to find desired results by typing - "I am looking for a cheap thumb drive made by Transcend". The search engine should then filter results in the background with the help of NLP and ML.

I think this should be the future of search. More human than machine.